# Can't stop React from updating the main component after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm having the following issue.

I have a component called "BackgroundService" who has a setInterval for requesting data from an API every 5 seconds. The received data from API is stored in "backgroundServiceResult" hook  with useState, located in App and shared by a context provider.

**_app.js:**

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

    const [backgroundServiceResult, setBackgroundServiceResult] = useState([false]);
    
    console.log("App reloaded")
    
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ backgroundServiceResult, setBackgroundServiceResult  }}>
            <BackgroundService/>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**BackgroundService.js:**

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import AppContext from '@/hooks/AppContext'

export const BackgroundService = () => {

    const { getLatestSyncInfo } = api()
    const { isDBSet, getJson } = OfflineStorage()
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
    const [alreadyNotified, setalreadyNotified] = useState(false)

    useEffect(async () => {

        const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            // REQUIRE DATA FROM API STUFF, AND CAll:
            appContext.setBackgroundServiceResult(data or stuff);

        }, 5000)

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [])

    return (
        <></>
    )
}
```

The problem is, every time the appContext.setBackgroundServiceResult is called from BackgroundService.js, the entire App component is re-rendered! so the "console log" in App is called, and all the components mounted again.

How can I store the received data from API through all my application without rendering again all from App?

Any way for solving this?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is following expected behaviour, when state or props update the component will re-render.

There are many options you could use to prevent this from negatively affecting parts of your application.

- `useEffect` could be used to only run code in child components when the component is initially mounted or when specific `props` or `state` change.
- `useMemo` could be used to only recalculate values upon specific `props` or `state` change.
- `useCallback` could be used to only recreate a function when specific `props` or `state` change.

In your specific case here it doesn't make sense to create the `BackgroundService` if it isn't going to render anything. Instead you should be creating a hook like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import AppContext from '@/hooks/AppContext'

export const useBackgroundService = () => {
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext);

    // Also bear in mind that the `useEffect` callback cannot be `async`
    useEffect(() => {
        // the `async` over here is fine though
        const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            appContext.setBackgroundServiceResult(data or stuff);
        }, 5000)

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, [])
}
```

And then call it in your app as follows:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const [backgroundServiceResult, setBackgroundServiceResult] = useState([false]);
    
    useBackgroundService();
    
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ backgroundServiceResult, setBackgroundServiceResult  }}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Don't worry about the `console.log` going off, it won't negatively affect your application. If you had to do something like sort a massive list at the top level of your app component you could do something like this:

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const [backgroundServiceResult, setBackgroundServiceResult] = useState([false]);
    
    useBackgroundService();

    const sortedList = useMemo(() => pageProps.myList.sort(), [pageProps.myList]);
    
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ backgroundServiceResult, setBackgroundServiceResult  }}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
    
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Then the `sortedList` value would only update when it needs to and your updated `backgroundServiceResult` wouldn't cause that value to be recalculated.

In the same way you could make use of `useEffect` in the children components to make sure code only runs on initial mount and not on the components being re-rendered.

If you update your question to be more specific about what problems your App being rendered are causing we could come up with a better solution to tackle that specific issue.